# Unable to access imported data on Cloud SQL with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, import, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to export a database from a CloudSQL SQL Server **Express** Database, that is currently attached on a user other than sqlserver, and import it on a new CloudSQL SQL Server **Standard** Database. While I can export/import normally with BAK files, I'm unable to create a new user on the destination database and grant it the db_owner on the imported schema, everything always goes only to the sqlserver user. Can someone help me out?

Best regards.

Comment: are you trying create the user with using t-sql ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what have you tried, for creating users and what output you received when you tried that.

But have you tried creating the user using gcloud cli? `gcloud sql users create`

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/users/create

You can assign the above user to access a specific database once it has been created using the command above.

Comment: I've created the user via GCP Console, the same as `gcloud sql users create`, the issue is being after this, I can't seem to get the right permission for the user to access the imported database.

Comment: Reading from manage users page: "Users created using Cloud SQL have all privileges except FILE and SUPER. If you need to change the privileges for a user, use the GRANT or REVOKE command in the mysql client."  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users. Have you tried resetting root user password as mentioned in the link above?

Comment: The link above is about mysql, not sure it's the same on SQL Server. On SQL Server https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/create-manage-users I didn't find any access to root user nor any GRANT permission access.

Answer (score 0):

If the new Standard Database is on a new Cloud SQL instance,  you might be using the new default MASTER database. By design, the "db_owner" role cannot be attributed there, so you may create a new database and grant the role on that new one instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but I can seem to find the correct role for this, every role I try gives me the error that it does not exists. And if I set the new user as owner of the database (via user mapping), I can see the database, but not the tables

Comment: Please explicitly list all steps performed, providing as much detail as possible with all commands, granting, and logging methods used.

Comment: Sure thing:

1. On the GCP Console, I went to the original database and exported it as a .BAK file
2. On the GCP Console, I went to the destination database, and imported the .BAK file
3. On the GCP Console, I went to the users and created the same user from the original database
4. On the SSMS I tried setting the new user as owner of the imported database, and got the error I mentioned

Comment: Please explicitly details the exact commands used while connected to the instance when setting the new user as owner, as well as providing the output from this query:

SELECT database_id, is_read_only, collation_name, compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'name_of_your_database';